# Finding blocks of connected columns of a data frame automatically in R

Tags: r, dataframe, split, missing-data

I have a data frame with missing values. There are groups of columns which are connected by values on the same rows and thus forming Blocks:

Block 1: Variables "X1", "X2" and "X3" /
Block 2: Variables "X4" and "X5" /
Block 3: Variables "X6"

```
x <- data.frame(matrix(NA, nrow = 5, ncol=7))

colnames(x)[7] <- "Block"

x[1, c("X1", "X2")] <- 7

x[2, c("X1", "X3")] <- 7

x[3, c("X4", "X5")] <- 7

x[4, c("X4")] <- 7

x[5, c("X6")] <- 7

x$Block[1:2] <- c(paste("X1", "X2", "X3"))

x$Block[3:4] <- c(paste("X4", "X5"))

x$Block[5] <- c(paste("X6"))
```

How can I create the variable "Block" indicating the connected groups automatically in R?

Comment: The question is unclear, specifically what do you mean by "indicating the connected groups"? Do you mean a variable that tells you which of the column groups are non-missing?

Comment: Can you explain output for 1st row? Why is it `X1 X2 X3` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the last column of `x` and convert to a logical matrix which is TRUE when not NA. From that create an incidence matrix `inc` and from that a graph `g`.  Compute the connected components `grps`. That will contain duplicates so compute the unique connected components `u` from that.  Then for each row in `ok` find the column names `nms` that correspond to entries and match that up with `u` giving the result.

```
library(igraph)

nc <- ncol(x) - 1
ok <- !is.na(x[, 1:nc])

inc <- sign(crossprod(as.matrix(ok)))
g <- graph_from_incidence_matrix(inc - diag(nc))
# plot(g)

grps <- groups(components(g))
u <- unique(lapply(grps, sort))
nms <- apply(ok, 1, function(x) colnames(ok)[x])
sapply(u, toString)[sapply(nms, function(x) which(lengths(lapply(u, intersect, x)) > 0))]
## [1] "X1, X2, X3" "X1, X2, X3" "X4, X5"     "X4, X5"     "X6"
```